# Is displays of Asus x550ze and Lenovo g565 interchangeable?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, laptop-repair

I want to replace the display of Asus x550ze by another one from Lenovo g565. Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Unlikely those displays are not user replaceable normally not are likely interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Asus display works on Lenovo laptop, it works, but brightness adjustment works weird.

Comment: @Ramhound not exactly.